# Fail2Ban ignore 404 of local redirect

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, fail2ban

Assume a bad actor scripts access to an Apache server to probe for vulnerabilities. With Fail2Ban we can catch some number of 404's and ban the IP. Now assume a single web page has a bad local reference to a CSS, JS, or image file. Repeated hits by the same legitimate site visitor will result in some number of 404s, and possibly an IP ban.

Is there a **good** way to separate these local requests from remote so that we don't ban the valued visitor?

I know all requests are remote, in that a page gets returned to a browser and the content of the page triggers more requests for assets. The thing is, how do we know the difference between that kind of page load pattern, and a script query for the same resource?

If we do know that a request is coming in based on a link that we just generated, we could do a 302 redirect rather than returning a 404, thus avoiding the banning process.

The HTTP Referer header can be used. If the Refer is the same origin as the requested page, or the same as the local site FQDN then we should not ban. But that header can be spoofed. So is this a **good** tool to use?

I'm thinking cookies can be used, or a session nonce, where a request might come in for assets from a page without a current session cookie. But I don't know if something like that is a built-in feature.

The best solution is obviously to make sure that all pages generated on a site include a valid reference back to the site, but we all know that's not possible. Some CMS add version info to files, or they adjust image paths to include an image size based on the client device/size. Any of these generated headers might simply be wrong until we can find and fix the code that creates them. Between the time we deploy something faulty and the time we fix it, I'm concerned about accidentally banning legitimate visitors with Fail2Ban (and other tools) that do not factor in where the request originates.

Is there another solution to this challenge? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> how do we know the difference between that kind of page load pattern

You don't in normal case (at least without some white- or black-list).
But you know URI- or paths segments, file extensions etc which would be rather never a target of such attack vectors, which you can ignore.

> Some CMS add version info to files, or they adjust image paths to include an image size based on the client device/size.

But you surely knows the prefixes that where correct, so an RE allowing some paths segments would be possible. For instance this one:

```regex
# regex ignoring site and cms paths:
^<HOST> -[^"]*\"[A-Z]{3,}\s+/(?!site/|cms/)\S+ HTTP/[^"]+" 40\d\s\d+
```

will ignore this one:

```
192.0.2.1 - - [02/Mar/2021:18:01:06] "GET /site/style.css?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 469
```

and match this one:

```
192.0.2.1 - - [02/Mar/2021:18:01:06] "GET /xampp/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 469
```

Similar you can write an regex with negative lookahead to ignore certain extensions like `.css` or `.js` or arguments like `?ver=1.0`.

Another possibility would be to make a special fallback location logging completely worse requests in special log-file (not into access or error logs), like described in [wiki :: Best practice](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic) so this way it would be possible to consider evildoers with definitely wrong URIs did not matching any proper location which can be handled by web server.
Or simply disable logging of 404 in known as valid locations (paths, prefixes, extensions whatever).

To ensure or completely avoid false positives you can firstly increase `maxretry` or reduce `findtime` and observe it a bit (so evildoers with too many attempts going banned and legitimate users with "broken" requests causing 404 but with not so large count of them will be still ignored). So you can cumulate whole list of "valid" 404 request of your application (in order to write more precise regex or filter it in some locations).